# Conditionally Formatting Spreadsheet Cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I am trying to create a Google Apps Script that will allow me to quickly determine if further action is needed by changing color of a cell. Currently I am performing an auditing process where I look at 5% of the product for errors. If too many errors are found, I need to look at 100% of the product.

I have been trying to create a script that upon meeting the error threshold will change the color of a cell and the following criteria is what needs to be met. I would use conditional formatting but opt for a script so that the escalation method is less apparent and so future expansion can manipulate formatting of text if needed.

- If a1 is less than or equal to 50 and b1 is less then four color cell c1 green
- If a1 is less than or equal to 50 and b1 is greater then four color cell c1 red
- If a1 is more than or equal to 50 and b1 is less than 4% of a1 then color cell c1 green
- If a1 is more than or equal to 50 and b1 is greater than 4% of a1 then color cell c1 red

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

---

```
function onEdit(e) { 
  var ss = e.source.getActiveSheet(); 
  var r = e.source.getActiveRange(); 
  if (r.getRow() != 1 && ss.getName() == "Entry Form") { 
    Error_Count = ss.getRange(r.getRow(),3).getValue(); 
    rowRange = ss.getRange(r.getRow(),1,1,3);

    if (Error_Count < 3.8) {
      rowRange.setBackgroundColor("#FF0000"); }
    else if (Error_Count == 'N/A') {
      rowRange.setBackgroundColor("#ffffff"); }
    else if (Error_Count > 3.9) {
      rowRange.setBackgroundColor("#ffffff");
    }
```

Comment: I updated my answer with a better idea of where you should be going with this code. I also included comments so you can get an idea of what is going on. However, your columns A-C in your spreadsheet don't have numerical values... so I have no clue how you plan to do comparisons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you mention "future expansion", but getting "a1", "b1" and "c1" specifically isn't very expandable.

My suggestion would be the following:

1. Use the [Sheet class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) to get "a1:c100" (columns a-c with 100 rows). Or maybe use `getLastRow()` of the [Sheet class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet), and then use [`getRange(1, 1, lastRow, 3)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange%28Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer%29) so that you have columns a-c with all rows that have data in them (best idea in my opinion).

   - Now you have your [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)
2. Get the values of that Range using the `getValues` function. This returns a matrix.
3. Since your values are in a matrix, **a1** would essentially be `values[0][0]`. **b1** would be `values[0][1]`, and **c1** would be `values[0][2]`.
4. You can easily loop through each "row" of values like:

   ```
   for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i ++) {
   // do your comparisons for each row.
   // row[0] is "a_rowNumber", row[1] is "b_rowNumber", etc.
   var row = values[i];
   ```
5. Now you can do your comparisons (which are purely mathematical, I think I'll leave them to you)
6. If a comparison like:

   ```
   if (row[0] > 50 && row[1] < 4)
   ```

   evaluates to true, you can use the `getRange()` function again like:

   ```
   getRange(i + 1, 3)
   ```

   Remember **i** is the row, and 3 is column c: add 1 to row because your array starts at index 0, but the actual row numbers on the spreadsheet (used by `getRange()` start at 1.
7. Once you have that Range (which is one cell at this point) you want to color in column c, use [`Range.setBackgroundColor()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setBackground%28String%29). In fact there are many ways you can set a background color, using RGB, hex color values or simple color values like "red". Take your pick!

**Edit**: Here is an example of how you can access the data you want, and how to use it:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // Get the variable "sheet" so that we can get more ranges and set colors later
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  // Get the edited cell so we can look at the current row
  var cell = e.source.getActiveRange();
  // Get the current row (which is the same row where the cell was edited)
  var editedRow = cell.getRow();

  if (cell.getRow() != 1 && sheet.getName() == "Entry Form") {
    // Get the actual values in that row (the ones we want to use, which are columns A-C)
    var rowValues = sheet.getRange(editedRow, 1, 1, 3).getValues();

    // Your first condition is met: get the current row, column 3 (current row, C), set background color
    if (rowValues[0] <= 50 && rowValues[1] < 4) sheet.getRange(editedRow, 3).setBackgroundColor("green");
    // Your second condition is met: get the current row, column 3 (current row, C), set background color
    else if (rowValues[0] <= 50 && rowValues[1] > 4) sheet.getRange(editedRow, 3).setBackgroundColor("green");
    // Your third condition is met: get the current row, column 3 (current row, C), set background color
    else if (rowValues[0] >= 50 && (rowValues[1] < .04 * rowValues[0])) sheet.getRange(editedRow, 3).setBackgroundColor("green");
    // Your fourth condition is met: get the current row, column 3 (current row, C), set background color
    else if (rowValues[0] >= 50 && (rowValues[1] >= .04 * rowValues[0])) sheet.getRange(editedRow, 3).setBackgroundColor("green");
  }
}
```

Comment: So I think this is a step in the right direction, but I think I was not clear enough. Here is an example of the [google doc](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AqtCuK7ex8ZNdHFXbzhwN2I5LVNMMllzODdsQ2NyU0E#gid=0) The total pieces does not change and the error count changes based on a entries added in b4-e. I have tried to manipulate what you offered but have not had success. I appreciate your assistance in advance.

Comment: If you have tried to use what steps I gave you, please post some code so that I can help you find the error. Logger and/or Execution Transcript from the Script Editor would help as well :)

Comment: I have added what I have but I continue to receive a syntax error. 
<!-- language: lang-none -->

Comment: -function onEdit(e) {
-if (e) { var ss = e.source.getActiveSheet();
-var r = e.source.getActiveRange(); 
-if (r.getRow() != 1 && ss.getName() == "Entry Form") {
-Error_Count = ss.getRange(r.getRow(),38).getValue();
-rowRange = ss.getRange(r.getRow(),1,1,3); if (Error_Count < 3.8) {
-rowRange.setBackgroundColor("#FF0000");
-} else if (Error_Count == 'N/A') {
                rowRange.setBackgroundColor("#ffffff");
            } else if (Error_Count > 3.9) { 
                rowRange.setBackgroundColor("#ffffff");

Comment: Best to update your question with your code. Don't post something like that in the comments because the comments are not formatted like posts. I will take a look at this in a bit...

Comment: @sergeinsas Thanks, I have no clue where I got the `5` and the `6` from. Losing my eyesight I suppose!

Comment: Thats so great thanks Chris. It now makes much more sense and your assistance is appreciated!

Comment: I'm glad that I could help :)